# Open LabView project and VIs as read-only?

Tags: labview

Is there a method of opening a LabView project and by extension any subVIs contained in the project as read-only?  There are occasionally times I want to poke around in the project and run certain VIs without the potential of a VI being accidentally changed.  I do have revision control in place, but the ability to open things as read-only would provide an extra layer of protection.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure LabVIEW to [tread read-only files (by attribute) as 'locked'](http://labviewwiki.org/LabVIEW_configuration_file/Miscellaneous#readOnlyLock). I am not sure if this goes for projects as well.